# Addition and Subtraction Assignment Operator With Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, variable-assignment, addition, subtraction

I would like to do an update by doing a simple addition on Sequelize.

table:

```
id || data
 1 ||  10
```

sample:

```
db.table.update({ data : 1 }, { where: { id: 1 }});
```

after this query

```
id || data
 1 ||  11
```

I know it's a simple question, but I could not find the solution.

Which operator can I add and subtract? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Here it is :**

```
db.table.update({ field: Sequelize.literal('data + 1') }, { where: { id: 1 }}))
```

**OR**

```
User.findById(1).then(user => {
  // -----> First Way
  return user.increment('my-integer-field', {by: 2});
  // -----> Second Way
  return user.increment([ 'my-integer-field', 'my-very-other-field' ], {by: 2})
  // -----> Third Way
  return user.increment({
     'my-integer-field':    2,
     'my-very-other-field': 3
  })
});
```

You can also do `decrement` by just replacing `increment` with `decrement`.

---

For Version6 :

```
await User.increment({age: 5}, { where: { id: 1 } }) // Will increase age to 15
await User.increment({age: -5}, { where: { id: 1 } }) // Will decrease age to 5
```

For more detail : **[DO READ](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#increment-decrement)**

Comment: update the docs link please

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize increment & decrement

```
myIncrementFunc(id, incrementor) {
  User.findById(id).then(user => {
    return user.increment('tableColumnName', {by: incrementor})
  }).then(user => {})
}
```

Code taken form sequelize Instances tutorial for Incrementing & Decrementing:
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/instances.html

Comment: can't access the link