# Sequelize how to update qty = qty + x

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to update the column qty like this

> qty = qty + x

My code is like this

```
db.Stock.update({
            qty: Sequelize.col('Stock.qty') + element.qty
        }, {
            where: {
                item_id: element.item_id
            }
        })
```

and my model, I have this also

```
{
    hooks: {
      beforeUpdate: function (Stock, options) {
        console.log("Stock", Stock._previousDataValues.qty);
      },
    }
  }
```

but this gives me the error

```
UPDATE `Stocks` SET `qty`='[object Object]10',`updatedAt`='2018-08-11 13:51:18' WHERE `item_id` = 8
```

I'm new to the sequelize and how can I successfully do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All you need is `literal` , try the below way :**

```
db.Stock.update({ 
        qty: Sequelize.literal(`qty + ${element.qty}`) // <---- HERE
    }, 
    { where: { item_id: element.item_id }
);
```

For More : **[Do Read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779426/2349407)**

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what I exactly need. =)