# Sequelize query to subtract value from previous row value

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using PostgreSQL. I have a reading value in my table. From that, I have to find the consumption by subtracting previous value.

I found the SQL query. How to use that in sequelize? Is there any other option except raw queries?

SQL Query:

```
SELECT "readingValue",
       "readingValue" - COALESCE(LAG("readingValue") OVER
           (ORDER BY "readingTime")) AS consumption
FROM public."tableName" LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779426/2349407 , this might help you with current one.

Comment: @VivekDoshi - I ll check with that

Comment: @VivekDoshi - I have checked that. That query is to update the record in the table. I don't want to update the table.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with sequelize literal.

```
model.update({'count': sequelize.literal('count + 1')}, { where: { id: 1 }})
```

You can also do it with increment method.

```
Model.increment('seq', { by: 5, where: { id: 'model_id' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would help, but you could also avoid using `LAG` and instead use a correlated subquery to find the lag value:

```
SELECT
    readingValue,
    readingValue - (SELECT t2.readingValue FROM public."tableName" t2
                    WHERE t2.readingValue < t1.readingValue
                    ORDER BY t2.readingValue DESC LIMIT 1) AS consumption
FROM public."tableName" t1;
```

Maybe this would be easier to phrase using your JavaScript ORM framework.

Comment: But subqueries tales more time than the MySQL LAG function.

Comment: Then use a raw query with `LAG`.  What are you asking here?

Comment: are there any other options except raw query? Because I have a complex where condition. that's why.

Answer (score 0):

We can use sequelize.literal for a field in attributes.

```
model.findAll({
        where: whereConditionObj,
        attributes: ['id','readingValue',
            [
                db.sequelize.literal('"readingValue" - COALESCE(LAG("readingValue") OVER (ORDER BY "readingTime"))'), 'Consumption'
            ]
        ],
        order: [['readingTime', 'ASC']],
        group:['id', 'readingValue']
    })
```